# Is there an R function that can convert datetime field which is in decimal form (41183.50417) to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: r, time, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I have an input file with datatime column which is filled with values of **format (41183.50417)**, how do I interpret this and convert to Timestamp?

I tried using Lubridate but the output is with Time zone, code shown as below

`as.POSIXct(as.Date(41183.50417, origin = '1900-01-01'),tz="")`

The output is as shown below

> 2012-10-03 20:06:00 +08

How do I get rid of this '+08', Though I have given tz="", it keeps getting displayed

I have come across Unix Timestamp/epoch etc but this format (41183.50417) isn't clear to me.

I expect the output of **41183.50417** to be **21/02/1999 10:21:20**

Comment: If you just want to get rid of timezone you could use `format`, `format(as.POSIXct(as.Date(41183.50417, origin = '1900-01-01')), "%Y-%m-%d %T")`

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah. It worked. Unable to mark this comment as solution as there is no option. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of timezone display we can use `format`

```
format(as.POSIXct(as.Date(41183.50417, origin = '1900-01-01')), "%Y-%m-%d %T")
#[1] "2012-10-03 20:06:00"
```

Read `?strptime` for more format details.

Comment: However when I use the below input "6/8/2169 9:40", it displays the time zone. Is the below code correct                                                                                     as.POSIXct('6/8/2169 9:40',format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M",tz=""). Since this isn't exactly decimal, I didn't use the above origin field. Any idea on where I am making mistake?

Comment: @SELVA you need to do , `format(as.POSIXct('6/8/2169 9:40',format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), "%Y-%m-%d %T")` . The `format` which you are using is a parameter in `as.POSIXct` function whereas the outer `format` is the function which we are applying.

Comment: Earlier, I used the same code but for different date format (6-8-2019 10:21:31) wthout format statement. It worked with tz=""(empty). Not sure why it isn't working now

Comment: Hello @Ronak Shah, Can you please let me know how to convert this character output (above output) to datetime(Posixct) format? I tried the below but it again gave me the timezone. Now I don't want to change the format but data type of the variable has to be changed                                                                    as.POSIXct(format(as.POSIXct('6/8/2169 9:40',format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), "%Y-%m-%d %T"),format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Comment: @SELVA If you want to keep them in `POSIXct` class it will display the timezone always because time by default has timezone.  You can remove timezone by using `format` as shown but then it will convert it into character.

Comment: Hi @Ronak Shah - can you help me with this post please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64311404/folder-in-github-is-missing-when-installed-as-r-package