# Folder in github is missing when installed as R package

Tags: r, github, download, devtools, pull

I have a public R package in [github](https://github.com/OHDSI/Aphrodite).

What I did was installed that package using the below commands

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("ohdsi/Aphrodite")  #APHRODITE is the package name
library(Aphrodite)
```

But I would like to make some changes to the way the package works.

Basically, I would like to make changes to the `functions.R` file under `R` folder in github.

As I used `install_github` command, I already have the package downloaded to my repository.

But I don't see the `functions.R` under `R` folder in my downloaded packages folder (APHRODITE).

Can help me understand how can I find the files to make changes?

Note: My appearance settings is set to show all hidden files and folder as well.

In github I see the below whereas in the downloaded packages folder (APHRODITE), I see something different. How can I find the `functions.R` file to make changes to the code locally?

[image]

Comment: Download the package using `git clone`, edit the code in the specific folder, and then install it using `devtools::install(path_to_package_folder)`. Installed packages do not have the source code. I believe the reasoning is that the code is actually bit-compiled in order to gain a quite massive performance boost when used in practice. Alternatively you could fork the repository on github, make your changes, and install the package from your forked repository.

Comment: Hi, thanks will try that. Would you mind writing it as an answer? In addition, may I know what does `install_github` function do? am not a computer science person I just follow the tutorials. So, why does `install_github` doesn't show us the required files?

Comment: I am not certain as for the **exact** reason why the folders do not match (I don't know how the package does it's stuff). But I assume that what it does is similar to `install.packages`, which downloads a compiled version of the package and then installs the compiled package. This is similar to calling `f <- compiler::cmpfun(function(x){ some code here })`. Basically it makes the code run faster. Sometimes quite significantly faster. One would probably have to dig down into the package development manual to understand the exact background.